# Why my hadoop output is many parts of file?

Tags: python, hadoop

I tried to count the frequency of word, and write the file:
`mapper.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()
    # increase counters
    for word in words:
        # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
        # what we output here will be the input for the
        # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
        #
        # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

use the hadoop statement:
`hadoop streaming \
    -input "/app/hadoop_learn_test/book.txt" \
    -mapper "python mapper.py" \
    -reducer "cat" \
    -output "/app/hadoop_learn_test/book_out" \
    -file "mapper.py" \`

the `book.txt` is:

```
foo foo quux labs foo bar quux
```

but I got 400 files named as `part-00000.gz` and when I use `hadoop dfs -cat path` to get the contents, I got nothing.

Why can't I got the result?

I use `cat book.txt | python mapper.py | sort`  in the local terminal and got the following:

```
bar     1
foo     1
foo     1
foo     1
labs    1
quux    1
quux    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have many output files is because Hadoop is a framework for distributing processes to many computers (and to many CPUs).  If you wanted only one file at the end, you'd only be able to do that with one process (/thread) thus voiding the entire point of Hadoop.

To cat the whole output, simply use a wildcard:

```
hadoop dfs -text path/p*
```

Note, you should use -text if your reading gz.

Also note that using `hadoop dfs` is deprecated, you should really be doing this:

```
hdfs dfs -text path/p*
```

ADDITION: Also using 1 reducer breaks fault tolerance in the reduce phase - i.e. if that 1 node goes down, the reduce phase will have to start from scratch.  One could have speculative execution on, but would often be a much less efficient use of resources than if we had many reducers.

Answer (score 0):

i think You need to use Counter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from collection import Counter

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()
    # increase counters
    wordcount=Counter(words)

    for word,count in wordcount.items():

        print '%s\t%s' % (word, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the mapred.reduce.tasks property to 1.

You can pass it to hadoop commnad line using -D mapred.reduce.tasks=1

To add: Each reducer in a Map Red job creates an output. So if you got 400 files basically you had 400 reducers.

Comment: Setting reducer to 1 is not a good idea as it will often slow down the reduce phase massively - i.e. throw away the whole point of MR - to do things in a distributed way.  In fact for many jobs it will just blow up and OOM.

Comment: @samthebest - Some points are valid. It does slow down the process. But to say it would throw away whole point of MR is a bit extreme. There might be various scenarios where i may want single reducer. Also OOM will only happen if you are using a list to store value - which is not recommended anyways.

Comment: If you have one process processing large amounts of data, and that process is memory intensive, then OOMs can occur.  For example in the Terasort algorithm the reducers perform a quicksort, which wants everything in memory. Trying to perform a Terasort with 1 reducer would very likely OOM. Joining would likely have problems too.  Furthermore 1 reducer will break fault tolerance, if that 1 node goes down, your reduce phase has to start from scratch.  Anyway, you say you can think of times where you want 1 reducer / file, please give examples.